# Abs[]^2 , Conjugate[], ComplexExpand[], and Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics, complex

I think this is a numeric problem but would like to see where it occurs. I create a complex rational polynomial as follows and make it a function of f

```
 bf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", 2, 2 \[Pi] 500.}];
  a = bf[I 2 \[Pi] f][[1, 1]]

(*
 9.8696*10^6/(((2221.44 - 2221.44 I) + 
   2 I f \[Pi]) ((2221.44 + 2221.44 I) + 2 I f \[Pi]))
*)
```

Now I use two methods for calculating the modulus squared.

```
b1 = ComplexExpand[Re[a Conjugate[a]]] // Simplify
b2 = ComplexExpand[Abs[a]^2] // Simplify
```

Why do I get two diferent answers?

```
(*

(0. + 0. I) + 3.90625*10^21/(6.25*10^10 + 1. f^4)^2 - (
 3.58535 f^2)/(6.25*10^10 + 1. f^4)^2 + (
 6.25*10^10 f^4)/(6.25*10^10 + 1. f^4)^2

(0. + 0. I) + 6.25*10^10/(6.25*10^10 + 1. f^4)
*)
```

I think this is to do with numerics because if I repeat with exact numbers

```
bf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", 2, 2 \[Pi] 500}];
a = bf[I 2 \[Pi] f][[1, 1]];
b1 = ComplexExpand[Re[a Conjugate[a]]] // Simplify
b2 = ComplexExpand[Abs[a]^2] // Simplify
```

I get two results the same.

```
(* 
62500000000/(62500000000 + f^4)

62500000000/(62500000000 + f^4)
*)
```

The problem is that I can't necessarily work with exact numbers. So why do I get  different answers? Is the problem in `ComplexExpand` or `Simplify`? Is there a preferential approach (I note that `Abs[]^2` gives simpler answers)? Thanks

Comment: `Rationalize[ approx, 0] ` will make an exact constant from the approximate constant **approx**.

Comment: @JohnDoty Thanks. I will look into this but I am not sure I can do this with more complex rational polynomials for my cases

Comment: As you go to more complicated polynomials, numerical instability problems worsen. Manipulating roots of polynomials can be problematic, too. But for those, *Mathematica* offers exact representation as `Root` objects, which you may use without stability concerns. For numerics, you'll be in the more difficult territory of "which polynomial form is best for this problem?" It's never power series...

Comment: While the structure of the two results are different, they are numerically equivalent. `Maximize[{Abs[b1 - b2], 0 < f < 10^9}, f]` evaluates to `{2.22045*10^-16, {f -> 0.0525412}}`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Interesting result. If you apply `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` to the difference of the answers you also get different answers. I would never have thought two different expressions could be so similar. I guess this is why Pade approximations are so good.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested what is the "right" answer. This can be easily found

```
bf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", 2, k}];
a = bf[I 2 π f][[1, 1]];
b1 = ComplexExpand[Re[a Conjugate[a]]] // Simplify
b2 = ComplexExpand[Abs[a]^2] // Simplify
```

Leading to 
$$\frac{k^4}{16 \pi ^4 f^4+k^4}$$
in both cases. I suggest to do numerics on this stage.

Comment: Thank you. This is useful. I should have stressed that this is a minimum working example. For more complicated filters, e.g. band pass of high degree the ability to work out the roots becomes more difficult and a numerical method is necessary. Still good to see the "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
bf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass", 2, 2 π 500.}];
```

Convert `a` to exact values

```
a = Rationalize[(bf[I 2 π f][[1, 1]]), 0] // Simplify;

b1 = ComplexExpand[Re[a Conjugate[a]]] // Simplify;

b2 = ComplexExpand[Abs[a]^2] // Simplify;
```

`b1` and `b2` are identical

```
b1 === b2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Further, with exact values it is not necessary to use `Re` in the definition of `b1`

```
b1 = ComplexExpand[a Conjugate[a]] // Simplify;

b1 === b2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```